# my .htaccess file not working with 404 error page in html

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

I'm trying to use .htaccess file in VS Code for the 401 and 404 errors, but when I try it out it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error401.html
```

I was expecting that when I entered an invalid address it would display the error page, but instead it displays the standard error page the cannot GET *the page* I've searched for answers on Stackoverflow, Codecademy forums, and on developer.mozilla.org. I also tried retyping the code, and using a debugger. The only remote problem I can think of is that I don't have an Apache web server.
My programming language is html.

Comment: You will need a server running apache or IIS with a htaccess plugin.

Comment: Try installing XAMPP if you want to test that out and your production server will have Apache installed

Comment: "it displays the standard error page" - What _exactly_ are you seeing?

Comment: @MrWhite this is what I get:<br/>'''Cannot GET /thepageyouentered

Comment: That's not the "standard" Apache (404) error page? So what is generating that response? (_EDIT:_ Ah, I've just noticed your last comment... "I don't have an Apache web server" - yes, that is the problem!)

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code with the problem is linked externally. Please [edit] this question to include the [minimal code that exhibits the issue](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. [Code linked externally may not be permanently available, and may not be licensed such that it can be used in answers](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` is a file for an apache server. It seems like you just have a directory with your project and open it in e.g. chrome with `C:/users/gabe/desktop/myProject`. `.htaccess` can't change anything about the fact that your browser tries to open a file that it can't find. The `.htaccess` isn't something your browser has access to (when you use it correctly on a server). That wouldn't make sense and would actually be a major security flaw because you would publish information about your server and its structure. Try installing an apache server. That will do the trick